# Taking the value from 'os.path.isdir' and using it in a true or false statement 'if' statement (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm currently trying to take the value (which should either return true or false based on if the folder exists) of `os.path.isdir` and then use it in a true or false statement. Here is my code so far:

```
from genericpath import exists
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Exists = os.path.isdir

#Moves into the Desktop Folder on your device.
os.chdir(path= r"c:\Users\binman\Desktop")

#Checks if folder exists; if not it makes it; if it does, it deletes it
if Exists == True:
    print("This folder does not exist! We will create it :D")
    os.mkdir("Produced Video")
    path = (r"C:\Users\binman\Desktop")

elif Exists == False:
    print("Folder exists! Deleting it :3")
    os.rmdir(path= r"C:\Users\binman\Desktop\Produced Video")
    os.mkdir("Produced Video")
    path = (r"C:\Users\binman\Desktop")
```

Now, my issue is that it doesn't do the action based on whether or not the folder is there. For example, if the folder already exitsts then it would need to delete it and then make a new one. And if there isn't a folder already. Right now it only tries to delete the folder and there is none so it throws a error message at me. here is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\binman\Documents\AutoVidMakeV2.py", line 25, in <module>
    os.chdir(path= r"C:\Users\binman\Desktop\Produced Video")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\binman\\Desktop\\Produced Video'
```

Any help is apprecated!

Comment: See how to use `exist` method, it takes string argument, your solution, do something completly different, it checks if `isdir` method exists
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-exists-method/

Comment: You just created an alias, but you never called the function: `Exists(r"c:\Users\binman\Desktop")`

Comment: `Exists = os.path.isdir` You're not actually _calling_ the function.  This assigns `Exists` to be a _reference_ to the `os.path.isdir` function object.  And as such, it will never equal `True` nor `False`

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic mistakes in your code. You have use the isdir function without any path to check. Also, you are using the Exists value incorrectly in your if else. Below is the corrected code that might help you:

```
from genericpath import exists
import os
import requests
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_folder = r"c:\Users\binman\Desktop"
path_to_check = r"C:\Users\binman\Desktop\Produced Video"
Exists = os.path.isdir(path_to_check)

#Moves into the Desktop Folder on your device.
os.chdir(path= root_folder)

#Checks if folder exists; if not it makes it; if it does, it deletes it
if Exists == False:
    print("This folder does not exist! We will create it :D")
    os.mkdir("Produced Video")

elif Exists == True:
    print("Folder exists! Deleting it :3")
    os.rmdir(path=path_to_check)
    os.mkdir("Produced Video")
```

Comment: Also, please look at the elif to see if you really intent to create the folder again immediately after deleting it. I didn't know your requirement properly, hence have left the mkdir there.